# Chrome JavaScript stops - reloading tab fixes it

Tags: chrome-for-android, javascript

[image: when it fails]

On my Samsung Galaxy Note II, when I visit StackOverflow it occasionally doesn't highlight interesting questions (which is done after the page has loaded).

I believe this is a Chrome issue, where JavaScript stops working. Closing the tab and reloading the site fixes the problem.

Has anyone else experienced this problem on Chrome for Android, and is there a fix? I have had browser updates and it still happens, but is difficult to replicate.

Here is how it should normally look:

[image]

Comment: Hasn't happened to me, but I've moved to the official app. You could try another browser, or the app, or Chrome Beta maybe?

Comment: Have you tried opening the Chrome developer tools to see what resources are not loaded? See [Remote Debugging Chrome On Android](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) for more info.